# Unable to download updated ruby for jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've tried to install Jekyll following this [tutorial](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/).

For some reason I can’t get ruby to update to the correct version. Ruby is supposed to 3.1.1p18 but my ruby only updates to 2.6.3p62

[image]

Comment: You might still be using the system install, could you check where `ruby` is by running `which ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` properly:

```
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-3.1.1
```

check if they are added using `cat ~/.zshrc` or `cat ~/.bashrc`, then close and reopen the terminal and check the ruby version.